# Windows scripting to email using TLS

Tags: email, ssl, blat

I'm trying to make an SVN post-commit script that makes backups to a Gmail drive.  Blat doesn't seem to support TLS.  Are there any good scripting programs on windows that can send an email via TLS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about other mail senders, but [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) is able to accept a plain text connection and tunnel it through an SSL connection.  You can have it listen on localhost:25 and make an SSL connection to an smtps server (tcp/465).  I have used it in a similar situation where a WebDAV client didn't support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

The blat folks are saying the stunnel is the best bet for tls support but i've found that gmail doesn't require tls to send mail.  Now, the data may not be encrypted but I send out email via my account (to other gmail accounts only) all the time as an automated process and it works great.  if you need it let me know and i'll drop in the command-line parms.